# Android coloring string to add to a string line

Tags: android, string, colors

I have this list method here which creates a list of events

```
  public List<Booking> createBookings(Date data) {
        ArrayList<Booking> events = new ArrayList<>();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String dateString = formatter.format(data);
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT ID, EVENT, LOCATION, START_DATE, START_TIME," +
                " END_DATE, END_TIME, COLOR FROM events WHERE START_DATE<= ? AND END_DATE>= ? ORDER BY START_TIME", new String[]{dateString, dateString});

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ...
                color = c.getString(7);
                String marker = setColor("•",color);
                ....
                Booking event = new Booking(eventID,marker+" "+start_time+" "+eventTitle+" \n"+durationStr+" "+durationStrHours+durationStrMins+location, data);
                events.add(event);
                Log.e("EVENTS", "Event ID - " + eventID + " Title - " + eventTitle);
            } while (c.moveToNext());

        }
        return events;
 }
```

What I would like to do is set color to particular string, getting color value from database

```
//This would take color code or name or however I choose to save the color value.
 color = c.getString(7);
```

And now I would like to set the color of that string by using something like this

```
  String marker = setColor("•",color);
```

So `setColor` method would return a colored string which then I could use to add to string line in `Booking`, which has 3 parameters, `Booking(Integer id, String title, Date date)`

```
Booking event = new Booking(eventID,marker+" "+start_time+" "+eventTitle+" \n"+durationStr+" "+durationStrHours+durationStrMins+location, data);
```

And as a result I would see only that particular string colored in the string line. So is someting like this possible ? I tried using `Spannable` but is was a no go, since in the end I need String object..

Comment: See this link [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37158126/clickablespan-not-clickable-in-custom-view-not-textview/37159456#37159456). This may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by setting a html string programmatically. For example, you could have a string resource like:

`<string>name="html_format"><[CDATA[<font color=%d>your coloured text</font>]]></string>`

Then at run time, you simply format the html with the colour you want and set it on your TextView with

`textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(formattedString));`

You can also use this technique to easily make sections of a TextView's text in bold with `<b>` tags. There's a limit to the Html that Android TextViews will accept though, not all of the formatting options are supported.